# How to hide BottomSheetDialogFragment after navigating to another fragment

Tags: android, kotlin, navigation, fragment, bottom-sheet

i have Fragment that include ImgaeView(s) in it's XML and i'm navigating from these images to another fragments but the problem is that the bottomsheet stays open, how to make it collapse when i navigate to another fragment?

here is a picture of the bottomsheet

[image]

and here i navigated to another fragment but the bottomsheet still appears on the screen

[image]

here is the code for inside the fragment

```
class MoreFragment : BottomSheetDialogFragment() {


override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
): View? {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_more, container, false)


}


override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)



    home_button.setOnClickListener{
        val homeFragment = HomeFragment()
        activity?.supportFragmentManager?.beginTransaction()
            ?.replace(R.id.nav_host_fragment, homeFragment, "findThisFragment")
            ?.addToBackStack(null)
            ?.commit()
        
    }
```

so my question is:

how to make it collapse down after i navigate to another fragment?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in Onclick listener before navigating to another fragment call dismiss() function

Comment: Great.. Just mark answer as verified so that others can benefit

Answer (score 0):

Just remove `.addToBackStack(null)` and call method `dismiss()`